# Onepage checkout sidebar not updated when edit information

Tags: magento, magento-1.7, checkout

I have magento onepage checkout process with only three step i.e

1. billing information
2. payment information
3. review

when i go through the process it will update sidebar but when edit using previous step it will not reflect on sidebar.

any help would be much appreciate.
[image]

Comment: can you  put checkout.xml

Comment: can you try with your base checkout.xml because you are using custom theme so there is change with missing any block or file

Comment: i have removed login and shipping step from the onepage checkout.so when in console check it add prevstep as parameter so when i go through the process it works perfect but when i edit previous step it will not change prevstep as billing instead it remain payment.so i think there is problem with js but i can't find the problem.